# Why aren't all job related methods in salesforce.bulk module marked isolated?

Tags: ballerina

Under the [salesforce.bulk module](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/module-ballerinax-sfdc/blob/master/salesforce/modules/bulk/client.bal), all the job/batch related methods are marked isolated except: [closeJob](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/module-ballerinax-sfdc/blob/0f6c0e9a2a7415813e3feee450ba823731221bbf/salesforce/modules/bulk/client.bal#L157) and [abortJob](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/module-ballerinax-sfdc/blob/0f6c0e9a2a7415813e3feee450ba823731221bbf/salesforce/modules/bulk/client.bal#L157).

Q. Why is that? Oversight?
I can't seem to determine what they can't be marked isolated.

I am facing an issue in my caller code due to this anomaly.

Answer (score 1):

These functions were not marked as isolated as it accesses data that are on a mutable state in their internal implementation.

I've just created issue about it, you can track progess here https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-extended-library/issues/482

Comment: "it accesses data that are on a mutable state" - what data is that?

Comment: The mutable data we are accessing is the payload of the request. As per the implementation for closeJob and abort Job functions, these payloads are not changing (constants) So we can provide an update for the connector with functions marked as isolated as per your requirement